# jQuery Accordion plugin - SHOPIFY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm hoping someone can help to answer my question...

I am currently using an accordion on my Shopify site to display some pretty extensive content. You can see a demo of what I'm using here: http://www.snyderplace.com/demos/accordion.html

I'm wanting to be able to create a link on my webpage that will take the customer to, say the 3rd panel of the accordion OPEN, but I just can't figure out what JS I need to be using to do this! Can someone help! Please?

Answer (score 0):

First thing that comes to my mind is passing a a meaningless # along with the link, like you would be going to a anchor. Then on page load check to see if the URL contains the hashtag, if true trigger the panel you want to open.

Link on initial page:

```
<a href="/newpag#panel-3" >link</a>
```

jQuery:

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf('#panel-3')){
   $('.thirdSection').trigger('click')}
```

I haven't tested this at all but with a bit of tweaking it should do the trick.

Comment: I added the code, but it did nothing. I see this piece of code in my .js...would this help with anything?

//opens a accordion panel
    function open($this, opts) {
        close(opts);
        //give the proper class to the linked element
        $this.removeClass(opts.cssClose).addClass(opts.cssOpen);

        //open the element
        opts.animateOpen($this, opts);

        //do cookies if plugin available
        if (useCookies(opts)) {
            // split the cookieOpen string by ","
            id = $this.attr('id');
            setCookie(id, opts);
        }
    }